# Homemade Tofu Firmness

Tags: tofu

So I am really getting into eating Tofu, and I want to get into making my own (since organic soybeans are alot cheaper then organic tofu).

My question is, whenever I buy Tofu I always by the firmest possible so it has the best protein to fat ratio.  When making your own tofu, is this something you can control, and if so, how do you?  In other words, how can I make sure that any home made tofu I make has the highest amount of protein to carbs/fat?

Answer (score 4):

The measure of firmness has to do with how much water is pressed out during processing. If you are making regular (non-silken) tofu, you will simply press the tofu longer to squeeze more water out of it. If you're also making the soymilk, I suppose you could make the milk thicker too to cut some of the pressing time.

Comment: But thicker store bought tofu has a higher protein ratio.  Changing the amount of water would not affect this.

Comment: @TaylorHuston Commercially made tofu may be fortified with soy flour or somesuch, which you could try (similar to making the soymilk thicker). In the nutritional labels I'm finding, the extra firm tofu seems to have a slightly higher level of all macronutrients, which makes sense. The extra processing removes water weight, concentrating everything else.